# Can we redirect a vpn traffic from a wanted port to a needed port?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, port-forwarding

I would like to connect to a friend who share me his vpn to access my documents remotely. At school most the "unnecessary" ports are closed, let's say his port is 1194.

Can I by anyway redirect my vpn connection (for example with a proxy hosted at my home) from the port 443 to 1194 so the connection would go out an open port and be redirected to the good port to my friend vpn ?

I don't know if I'm clear enough so I made a little schema:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, that's possible – the proxy just needs to accept your connection to proxy:443 and make one to friend:1194, i.e. it needs to do basically what a proxy does.

Most such proxies deal only with TCP (which OpenVPN supports but does not recommend using), but there should be some that can relay UDP streams as well. But keep in mind that firewall rules apply to TCP and UDP separately – just because TCP port 443 is open, doesn't mean UDP port 443 will be.

Another method would be to use DNAT and SNAT on your home router (like "NAT hairpin" or "NAT reflection", it's often used for inside-inside "port forwarding" but could equally be used for outside-outside relaying). This should work equally well for both TCP and UDP. However, most home routers don't allow flexible enough configuration.

Finally, because this is a VPN, you could set up a permanent connection *from home* to your friend's VPN, and then set up your own VPN from school to *your* home server, and configure routing to correctly forward packets between the two networks. (It would be just like forwarding packets between two Ethernet LANs.)

I would generally recommend the 3rd option, as it would only involve very typical network configuration (i.e. no special proxies or anything) and also lets you use a more convenient VPN protocol for connections from school (e.g. you can use WireGuard if your friend uses OpenVPN, or vice versa).

Comment: do you have any link for me to get started with the third option ? I know basics about OpenVPN (what my friend uses)